# I'd like to use several Highcharts using different data but same options

Tags: jquery, dynamic, highcharts

Based on the Highcharts demo, I have the following in my html:

```
<div class="container" style="height: 300px; width:500px"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="charts.js"></script>
```

And the following my charts.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.container').highcharts({
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        chart: {
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: false
        },
        title: {
            text: label
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage}%</b>',
            percentageDecimals: 1
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    color: '#000000',
                    connectorColor: '#000000',
                    formatter: function() {
                        return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ this.y;
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Space',
            type: 'pie',
            data: [
                ['Used',   used - 0 ],
                ['Free',   free - 0 ],
            ]
        }]
    });
});
```

It's a pie chart that displays drive info. However, I have a script that generates this data dynamically (depending on how many drives there are) so I don't want to have to create a new chart for each drive. I want to create a div dynamically (this will be in php so I can set a foreach loop) and call the pie chart for each drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not create the chart in the php loop as well and call `.highcharts` for each chart?

If you want to create a single config object use jQuery's [extend](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) method.

Fiddle example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/aAA8x/1/).

```
// create your base config
var baseConfig = {
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    chart: {
        plotBackgroundColor: null,
        plotBorderWidth: null,
        plotShadow: false
    },        
    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage}%</b>',
        percentageDecimals: 1
    },
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            allowPointSelect: true,
            cursor: 'pointer',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                color: '#000000',
                connectorColor: '#000000',
                formatter: function() {
                    return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ this.y;
                }
            }
        }
    }
};

// create your data
var data1 = {title: {
        text: 'One'
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Space',
        type: 'pie',
        data: [
            ['Used',  30],
            ['Free',  70],
        ]
 }]};

 var data2 = {title: {
        text: 'Two'
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Space',
        type: 'pie',
        data: [
            ['Used',  60 ],
            ['Free',  40],
        ]
  }]};

  //combine them
  $('#container1').highcharts(
      $.extend(baseConfig, data1)
  );

  $('#container2').highcharts(
    $.extend(baseConfig, data2)
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using many pie charts/containers you can only push appropriate amunt of series.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/u7FQS/18/

```
series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'testname1',
            center: [70, 140],
            showInLegend: true,
            data: [
                ['Commerce', 33.0],
                ['Engineering', 32.3], {
                    name: 'Financial Services',
                    y: 18.8,
                    sliced: true,
                    selected: true
                }, ['Logistics, Aviation & Shipping', 5.5],
                ['Seafood & Marine', 9.2],
                ['Corporate Services & others', 1.2]
            ]
        }, {
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'testname2',
            center: [230, 140],
            showInLegend: false,
            data: [
                ['Commerce', 33.0],
                ['Engineering', 32.3], {
                    name: 'Financial Services',
                    y: 18.8,
                    sliced: true,
                    selected: true
                }, ['Logistics, Aviation & Shipping', 5.5],
                ['Seafood & Marine', 9.2],
                ['Corporate Services & others', 1.2]
            ]
        }, {
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'testname3',
            center: [390, 140],
            showInLegend: false,
            data: [
                ['Commerce', 33.0],
                ['Engineering', 32.3], {
                    name: 'Financial Services',
                    y: 18.8,
                    sliced: true,
                    selected: true
                }, ['Logistics, Aviation & Shipping', 5.5],
                ['Seafood & Marine', 9.2],
                ['Corporate Services & others', 1.2]
            ]
        }, {
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'testname4',
            center: [550, 140],
            showInLegend: false,
            data: [
                ['Commerce', 33.0],
                ['Engineering', 32.3], {
                    name: 'Financial Services',
                    y: 18.8,
                    sliced: true,
                    selected: true
                }, ['Logistics, Aviation & Shipping', 5.5],
                ['Seafood & Marine', 9.2],
                ['Corporate Services & others', 1.2]
            ]
        }]
```